# Why do processes have UID/GID?

Tags: process, uid

What's the point of UID and GID in processes' parameters?

There is EUID, RUID, SUID (and for Linux FSUID) that determine process privileges. I can't think what's the use of UID/GID in such scenario.

Just to give an example, if in one terminal I run `$ passwd`, and in the other print process parameters, then I get the following output

```
$ ps -Ao uid,euid,ruid,suid,cmd | grep passwd
0     0  1000     0 passwd
```

So it is seems like UID was changed to EUID. Is there any particular reason for this behaviour?

Comment: In your example, the `passwd` command gets to run via elevated privileges (via setuid) and still know which user executed it.

Comment: @jordanm I know this very well and this is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ps -Ao uid,euid,ruid,suid,cmd | grep passwd
0     0  1000     0 passwd
```

`uid` and `euid` in format specifier and selectors of the `ps` from procps/Linux are exactly the same thing; `uid` is an alias for `euid`.

From `man ps`:

```
STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS
       ...
       euid        EUID      effective user ID (alias uid).
       ...
       uid         UID       see euid.  (alias euid).
```